# I can not access some html code of a page

Tags: html, web-scraping

I’m trying to make web scraping in a web page, but there is code that I can’t reach. The part of the code of the page that I cannot achieve is accessed through an anchor tag. In the html is:

```
<a class="MTLink" href="#d192633539-47" title="example" >
```

But when I click on "#d192633539-47" does not appear what is intended, ie not appear that appears when I click on the link on the page. Instead appears another page. 
Related to this I have also

```
<li id="d192633539-47" class="MainTabContent Hidden" tnIndex="192633539">
```

Someone can help me? What could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This element is controlled by JavaScript. Without tracing the JS code you cannot determine the intention of the click event.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with wrong cookie handling. Check it out.